# Spring with maven

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I would like use spring and maven for a webservice and when i start the application i have this problem:

```
 Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec 
 (default-cli) on project WebService: Command execution failed. Process 
 exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fr.itevents</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>WebService</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Please show more of the error output. I'm guessing this will reveal more about which process was started by the exec plugin and why it failed with a non-0 exit code.

Comment: Please provide full stack of error, this will help to track issue.

Comment: You are using spring boot, then use spring boot instead of working around it. Remove all the plugins, leave only the spring boot one and do `mvn springBoot:run`. Also remove the Java EE dependency you don't need it and will make your life harder, the spring starters already manage that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring Boot and are trying very hard not to use it, at least in your `pom.xml`. First you don't need the `javaee-web-api` dependency. The idea of the starters is that those manage all needed dependencies. So simply remove it. The same applies to the `spring-boot-starter` as that already is implied by the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency.

You have defined a lot of additional plugins for which Spring Boot already has the needed configuration, which you are now overriding or even worse using a very old version. Remove all the plugins and leave only the Spring Boot one.

So what you basically need to do is simply strip your `pom.xml` which should leave you with something like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>fr.itevents</groupId>
<artifactId>WebService</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>WebService</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>   

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>   
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**Pro Tip:** I would suggest using a *jar* instead of a *war* that way you can simply deliver a `jar` file and do `java -jar WebService.jar` and have everything up and running in no time. You don't really need a war for that anymore.